# SSRS Report stopped working

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am working on SSRS report. Here is the cs file code:

```
new protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String reportTitle = GetValueFromQueryString("ReportTitle");
            /* Get Agency name and set it in report parameters */
            AgencyBO agencyBO = new AgencyBO();
            Agency agency = new Agency();
            agency = agencyBO.GetAgencyInformation();
            List<ReportParameter> lstParam = new List<ReportParameter>();
            lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("Agency", agency.Name));

            /* Declare parameters that are to be sent to Report Helper class */
            string orderBy = string.Empty,
                   startAge = string.Empty,
                   endAge = string.Empty,
                   sex = string.Empty,
                   staffId = string.Empty,
                   statusId = string.Empty,
                   ethnicityId = string.Empty,
                   treatmentProviderId = string.Empty;

            ConsumerSummaryReportCriteria consumerSummaryReportCriteria = new ConsumerSummaryReportCriteria();
            Dictionary<String, String> lst = consumerSummaryReportCriteria.GetReportParams();
            foreach (var pair in lst)
            {
                /* ---- Set parameters that are to be sent to Report Helper class ---- */
                if (pair.Key == "orderBy" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    orderBy = pair.Value;
                }
                if (pair.Key == "startAge" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    startAge = pair.Value;
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("startAge", pair.Value));
                }
                if (pair.Key == "endAge" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    endAge = pair.Value;
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("endAge", pair.Value));
                }
                if (pair.Key == "gender" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    sex = pair.Value;
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("gender", pair.Value));
                }
                if (pair.Key == "staffIds" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    staffId = pair.Value;
                }
                if (pair.Key == "consumerStatusIds" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    statusId = pair.Value;
                }
                if (pair.Key == "ethnicityIds" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    ethnicityId = pair.Value;
                }
                if (pair.Key == "treatmentProviderIds" && pair.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    treatmentProviderId = pair.Value;
                }

                /* ---- Set parameters to report parameters list that are to be sent to 
                 * RDLC to show report selection criteria at the end of the report ---- */
                if (pair.Key == "staffNames")
                {
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("staffNames", pair.Value));
                }
                if (pair.Key == "consumerStatusNames")
                {
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("consumerStatusNames", pair.Value));
                }
                if (pair.Key == "treatmentProviderNames")
                {
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("treatmentProviderNames", pair.Value));
                }
                if (pair.Key == "ethnicityNames")
                {
                    lstParam.Add(new ReportParameter("ethnicityNames", pair.Value));
                }
            }

            ReportHelper.ApplyReportSetting(ref rptConsumerSummaryReport, reportTitle, orderBy, startAge, endAge, sex, staffId, statusId, ethnicityId, treatmentProviderId);

            rptConsumerSummaryReport.LocalReport.SetParameters(lstParam);
            rptConsumerSummaryReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

It was working perfectly but suddenly stopped working.
A blank aspx page opens and report viewer does not open.

Here is the code of aspx file.

```
<form id="frmConsumerSummaryReport" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scmReport" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptConsumerSummaryReport" runat="server" Height="100%" AsyncRendering="False"
        Width="100%" SizeToReportContent="True" Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Consumer\ConsumerSummaryReport.rdlc">
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some new parameters in my report after that it stopped working. No idea why this happened. After removing those parameters, it's working fine again.

EDIT: It was so because those parameter had null value. When I set their property to Allow "" and null values, it started working.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. You added parameters to .rdl. Would help if you informed about this at the beginning :D.

Comment: yeah I trust u :P can you help me in another SSRS-related problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252561/ssrs-sum-in-table-group

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://otkfounder.blogspot.com/2007/11/solving-reportviewer-rendering-issue-on.html.

If you didn't change the code or reports it can be something with IIS configuration. This link helped me more than twice to solve that kind of problems. For start make sure you have handler described there added. If not, add it and test if it works.

If it doesn't work, then you'll have to play with web.config to get it right (example of correct entry is there).

Comment: No. VS is using ASP.NET Development Server.

Comment: So maybe give IIS a try? At least you'll know if you're code is ok.

Comment: I know my code is ok because it was working very fine few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a ReportViewer & LocalReport through markup (as you have) has been reported to have a history of issues. You will get much better results if you replace

`<rsweb:ReportViewer>...</rsweb:ReportViewer>`

with a simple div like:

`<div id='reportContainer' runat='server'></div>`

Then within your code behind you instantiate your ReportViewer and populate the local report and then just add that as a control to the div.

In my report manager class a reference to the div is part of the constructor like:

`public ReportManager(HtmlContainerControl ReportContainer){...}`

leading to a 'showTeport method' that just drops the viewer into it like...

```
private ReportViewer ShowReport(string ReportName, DataSet ds)
   {
      try
      {
         _activeDS = ds;
         string ReportFileName = ResolveRDLCName(ReportName);
         var viewer = new ReportViewer();

         viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = ReportFileName;
         viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;

         //AssignReportParameters(viewer.LocalReport);

         foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
         {
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(ds.DataSetName + "_" + dt.TableName, dt));
         }

         viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);

         _ReportContainer.Controls.Add(viewer);

         return viewer;
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
      {...}
```

Now, obviously, there is a lot more to it than this, but what I have shown should get you to a more reliable solution.

Comment: I do not want to change anything in this way.. as it was working very fine previously