# SSRS Sum in table group

Tags: reporting-services, sum, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am working on SSRS reporting services.
I have a table on which I applied group. Originally I had this data:

[image]

I changed something in my tablix and created a tablix and added a parent group of Age i.e. left column and then in the right column, I applied an expression: `=SUM(Fields!AgeTotal.Value, "Group1")`
which made the result like this:
[image]

Now I want 3,3,3 and 2,2 not to repeat and make them 1 row of each group.
Like this: [image]

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right Click on the details cell and select add Total, then right click on the entire details rows and change it's visibility to Hide.
This should do the trick!

**EDIT**

Setp by step tutorial with Image:

First image example: on the left the result you want, on the right the result you get from a simple grouping.
I'm getting the sum(but you could use a count or whatever aggregation you want) of the field lam_larghezza (which, for your information, is a width) group by different lam_spessore values (which, is a thickness)

I'm sorry but mi IDE is in Italian so here a simple translation:

*Aggiungi* -> Add
*Gruppo* -> Group
*Righe* -> Rows
*Raggruppa per* -> Group By
*Totale* -> Total
*Dividi Celle* -> Split Cell
*Visibilità Righe* -> Row visibility

[image]

**Let's start!**

Create the dataset for the report and clean the report

Add a table to the report

[image]

Add the detail field in the data row

[image]

Right click on the full row
Add group -> Row group -> father group -> group by grouping field (should be age)

[image]

[image]

Click on the detail cell (only the cell not the entire row, and remember that the cell had to be highlighted not the text inside the cell, because two different contex menu appear) -> Add Total

[image]

You now have 1 grouping cell and two detail cell

split the grouping field cell

[image]

set the visibility of the detail row to hidden

[image]

*And you are done!*

[image]

Comment: This could work if Total works for each group individually. Total displays the total at the footer of the table. The answer of total is 5.

Comment: i made a test and total works for groups too... can you show the layout of the report?

Comment: added a step by step solution

Comment: em sorry il_guru but some things are really confusing. e.g. `Step 3 Add the detail field in the data row` and some other as well in coming steps. I will be very thankful to you if you add screen shots with these steps. because im not fully getting the steps. Thank you so much for your concern

Comment: Not have time now at work to do screens, i maybe can provide them later or tomorrow. In my simple example i consider you have two field in the query, the one your are grouping on and the value you are counting/summing (eg: Age, Name and you want the count of all the people with that age), so the detail field is Name while the grouping field is Age. Hope this could help for now

Comment: In my first picture, I have shown two columns, Age and total. Are you talking about these two fields returned by query? if im not wrong

Comment: please take your time and provide screenshots whenever get free from your work,it would b great if you can provide them today or tomorrow. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: i think i cannot do more than this

Comment: Thanks il_guru, you helped a lot. One last thing to ask is: in my IDE, I have Add Total option disabled on the cell on which you applied add total. I can only set add total on group field. Hope you are getting. You can see my edited question for that. If you find any reason for this, please let me know, Otherwise you really did the best for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I noticed that if in your cell you put an expression it disable the Add Total option. Is this?

Comment: No, it does not allow to add total on any cell either having expression or not except Group cell. e.g. I can add total in only `lam spessore`

Comment: it's okay no problem. You helped a lot. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I hope this answer can help many other people so I'm marking this as answer .