# How to enable Add Total option in Tablix

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ide, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I had a problem of couting sum of grouped rows in a tablix. I posted it on stackoverflow. There I found the detailed answer by a user. But the problem is now, he is asking me to add "Add Total" in one cell of my tablix. Whereas I find no option of adding Add Total on every cell. In fact it is disabled on each cell except the cell that is coming under a group.

The person is using Italian IDE (Visual Studio) whereas my IDE is in english. Is there any difference between these two?

Please see the detailed post and reply if there is any solution.

I'll be thankful.

[SSRS Sum in table group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252561/ssrs-sum-in-table-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/704cdb88-de26-44fc-91d4-7e0ddbba0e2f)

This is an alternate solution to my problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I think the problem is if the field is not recognised as a numeric, then 'Add Total' field will be disabled. So to overcome this problem, first I inserted a row at the bottom of the table and then  I converted the field into double in the expression as follows

```
=SUM(cdbl(Fields!GROSS_MARGIN.Value))
```

After running the report, I was able to see expected total.

Answer (score 0):

Make column properties for which u want totals as double or decimal in dataset.
Refresh report data in report designer. U will be able to see add total as enabled. Right click on column for which u want to add total and select Add Total.

Answer (score -2):

no there is no differnce between it